# Change image based on Theme selection for Light or Dark

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'am creating a Windows Phone 8.1 app in which I use a number of images that should be shown according to the selected Theme Light or Dark.

The Light and Dark image are created with the correct naming and scaling.

I've created the following ThemeResource to set the Image Source according to the selected Theme.

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
            <Style x:Key="ShowImage" TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="Assets/image.png"/>                            
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
            <Style x:Key="ShowImage" TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source" value="Assets/image.png"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>                
    </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

And the XAML to show the Image as necessary.

```
<Grid>        
    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
           Stretch="None" 
           Style="{ThemeResource ShowImage}">
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

When I start the app with a theme selected the correct image is shown every time. However when I select a different theme and then switch back to my app I can see that the background color is updated however my image is not updated dynamically.

As far as I'am aware the ThemeResource should be used to update this dynamically but I can't get it to work. 
Does anybody know what is wrong with my XAML code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted works perfectly fine for me. Can you post more details on how to reproduce the issue. This is what I have done.

1. Opened the app
2. It displayed correct image according to theme
3. Minimized app using Start button
4. Changed theme and restored app

It changed both, the background and corresponding image.
Please check again if you are making some other mistake and in the code your posted you are setting image source to same image in both the themes

```
<Setter Property="Source" value="Assets/image.png"/>
```

Comment: Hi Akshay, Thanks for your answer. The process you describe to verify is the same that I have used. I tested on one of the Windows Phone 8.1 simulators and also deployed to my own Windows Phone device. For both same behaviour.

Comment: Additionaly I've named the image files according to the naming convention described at MSDN [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965324.aspx) so this results in `image.scale-240_theme-light.png`. And also a file for the dark theme offcourse. The file then should be referenced by using the name as `image.png`. The whole setup I use is additionaly based on another stackflow article [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24326363/changing-background-image-based-on-localsettings) as answered by Galinho. Is there a way to debug the Theme switch behavior at runtime?

Comment: If you are using the naming conventions, why are you actually creating a ThemeDictionary? Simply setting `Source="Assets/image.png"` will achieve the same task.
Using the naming conventions, the image source will not change until the app is reloaded into the memory. Use two different names in the ThemeDictionary so that the image can update at runtime.

Comment: Hi Akshay, so I tried that putting in the complete file name for both themes in the Image Source. That worked for switching but the scaling didn't work correctly anymore. So I tried next changing the filenames to e.g. `image-light.scale-240_theme-light.png` and then referencing it in the Setter by `imagelight.png`. And that worked for switching the Theme and the Scaling. Thanks for you support. My issue is now solved.

Comment: That exactly is what I meant! Good to know its working now :)